# Scaling SVG coordinates, but not elements

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have a bunch of `<circle>` elements, and I want to zoom in on them.

I want to go from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Notice that I'm *not* enlarging the circles, only the distance between them.

How can I efficiently do this? What I'm doing right now is to setting the `cx` and `cy` coordinates individually on each circle. This works, but is slow when I've got thousands of circles.

I can put them all in a `<g>` and scale that with `transform: scale(x);`. This is a lot faster, but it will scale both the distances and the size of the circles.

Is there any way to scale the coordinates independently of the circle radius? Can I specify the circle radius in units that relative to screen size, for instance?

I'm using d3 for this, but any solution is appreciated.

Comment: When you said *"I want to zoom in on them"* are you using `d3.zoom` or was that just an expression?

Comment: I am using `d3.zoom`, but `d3.zoom` is just setting `cx` and `cy` and each circle. So I don't think this relates much to d3 actually, but is more about what SVG in a browser can do.

Comment: BTW, I've switched to scaling `g` with `transform: scale(x)`, and then scaling `r`on each `circle`. This speeds things up since I'm now doing half the work - I'm setting only one property (r) instead of two (cx, cy). Still, I'm setting thousands of properties every frame, so it would be nice to find a better way of doing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach IMO is to use zero-length lines, with rounded end caps, to form your circles.  You set their diameter using `stroke-width`.  Then you can use `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` to prevent them from scaling when you enlarge the SVG.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect

`vector-effect` is supported by most modern browsers.

```css
svg {
  background-color: black;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
}


path:nth-child(3) {
  stroke: plum;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M 20,20 h 0"/>
  <path d="M 20,40 h 0"/>
  <path d="M 30,50 h 0"/>
</svg>



<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="M 20,20 h 0"/>
  <path d="M 20,40 h 0"/>
  <path d="M 30,50 h 0"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ha! 0-length lines with round ends... Now *that's* thinking outside the (view)box ;*)

Comment: It's a nice answer, very clever, upvoted etc... But there is a *but*: I'm seeing those "circles" enlarged. In Safari/OS X, the small ones are 6px x 6px, while the bigger ones are 10px x 10px. Implementation differences?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the kind of trickery I was hoping someone could come up with. As long as I scale using the viewBox property (and not transform:scale(n)), this seems to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks for that report @GerardoFurtado. It may actually be a deal breaker if this doesn't work in Safari :(

Comment: What about `vector-effect: non-scaling-size`? Is it unsupported?

Comment: @Sasha That's a proposed new value for SVG2. I might be wrong, but I don't believe any browsers support the new values yet (ie those other than `non-scaling-stroke`)